# Set default Value in DataGrid XAML

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I am working onto an a datagrid, and everything worked fine until I observed if I delete the first row I got a lots of problems.

The objective

1. The DataGrid Is binded to an observable collection
2. The User can add new rows and delete them, but I need at least one default rows.

so the XAML code is :

```
<toolkit:DataGrid x:Name="MainGrid" 
    ItemsSource="{Binding StrategieList}" 
    SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedStrategie, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, Converter={StaticResource ignoreNewItems}, Mode=TwoWay }"

    AutoGenerateColumns="False" 
    DockPanel.Dock="Top"
    MouseMove="OnMainGridMouseMove"
    DragEnter="MainGrid_DragEnter_1" 
    DragLeave="OnMainGridCheckDropTarget"
    DragOver="OnMainGridCheckDropTarget"
    Drop="OnMainGridDrop" DataContextChanged="OnMainGridDataContextChanged"
    CanUserAddRows="False">
```

The Observable collection is manipulated a bit in code behinf for some personnal reasons I don't show you everything here.

In the model view you can see the observable collection is managed:

model view constructor :

```
public ControlorStrategies(){
    _pStrategie = new ObservableCollection<StrategieDescription>();         

    _pStrategie.CollectionChanged += AvailableStrategyChanged;
    _selectedstrategie.PropertyChanged += ListIdChanged;       
}
```

Now the delegates is :

```
 private void AvailableStrategyChanged(object sender, System.Collections.Specialized.NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs e)
{

    if (e.Action == System.Collections.Specialized.NotifyCollectionChangedAction.Add)
    {
        this._pStrategie.Last().PropertyChanged += ListIdChanged; //subscribe the latest element add to the events  
        //Warning create the strategy modifying the current strategies
        this.list_of_strategies.AddNewStrategie();
        for (int i = 0; i < _pStrategie.Count; i++)
            StrategieList[i].HasNewButton = false;                   
        StrategieList.Last().HasNewButton = true;
        StrategieList.Last().StrategyNumber = StrategieList.Count-1;
        StrategieList.Last().PropertyChanged += ListIdChanged;                             
    }

    //we delete the strategy
    if (e.Action == System.Collections.Specialized.NotifyCollectionChangedAction.Remove)
    {                
        //in case there is no more strategies the objects should be liberated
        if (StrategieList.Count == 0)
        {
            _pStrategie.CollectionChanged -= AvailableStrategyChanged;   
            list_of_strategies.ListOfStrategies.RemoveAt(e.OldStartingIndex);
            _pStrategie.Add(new StrategieDescription()); 
           _pStrategie.CollectionChanged += AvailableStrategyChanged;
           _pStrategie.Last().PropertyChanged += ListIdChanged;            
        }
        //Affect the normal color to the objects
        else
        {
            //Delete the users data affected to the objects
            DeleteUserDatas.SuppressUserDatasWithId(SelectedStrategie.ListId);
            list_of_strategies.ListOfStrategies.RemoveAt(e.OldStartingIndex);
            _pStrategie.Last().HasNewButton = true;
        }          
    }

    if (StrategieList.Count > 0)
        first_id = StrategieList.First().ListId;   


}
```

Now I can explain the problem: 
The datagrid is divided in column and work pretty fine, except if I delete rows, the behavior from the first row doesn't work exactly as I want-> To be more precise I can't erase the button on the first row.
Loo at the XAML code to understand

```
<toolkit:DataGridTemplateColumn Header="">
    <toolkit:DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <Button Name="AddStrat" Content="Add new strategie" Visibility="{Binding HasNewButton, Converter={StaticResource BoolToVis}}" Click="AddStrat_Click_1" />

        </DataTemplate>
    </toolkit:DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
</toolkit:DataGridTemplateColumn>
```

Does anybody have any idea why, when erasing every row, only the first row behave the button also the value is equal to false?